# URL for ALAssets are all the same

Tags: iphone

I print out a number of ALAssets and they all have the name public.someFileType

> Added asset ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:{
>       "public.jpeg" = "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000020&ext=JPG";
>   }

Is that something I need to be concerned about or should I just focus on

> "//asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000020&ext=JPG";

IS there an easy way of getting the filename of the Asset. I asked a similar question and I got a great answer but it seems overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the URL is really the "//asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000020&ext=JPG" part. There is no way to get the real filename that is officially supported by Apple.